# Only rel="prev" attribute

Tags: seo, html, pagination, rel

At my site I can set only `<link rel='prev' />` without `next` part. Will robots index pages in appropriate way (show first page instead of random page from list) with only `prev` attr?

Comment: I would suggest not to waste time on partial implementation. If you really want to handle SEO for pagination then implement next as well... Their should be some flag to signal adding a rel next tag

Comment: If I add "noindex follow" to each page in sequence (excluding first) will I get rid of `<link>?pageNumber=X` in search results but links from these will be still crawled and indexed?

Answer (score 1):

On the last page you only need to use PREV. This is detailed on Google's help page regarding [Indicate paginated content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en).

> On the final page of the sequence (`http://www.example.com/article-part4.html`>), add a link pointing to
>   the previous URL, like this:
>
> `<link rel="prev" href="http://www.example.com/article-part3.html">`
>
> Because this is the final URL in the sequence, there’s no need to add
>   a rel="next" link.

Comment: Yeah, I read this. But I have SPA, so I don't know is there a next page before data from server loaded.

Comment: It's pointless to use PREV without a NEXT.... if indeed a next page exists, unless it is the final page as mentioned. If you can't use NEXT... do not use PREV or better yet... fix your code so that both work.